# Как проверить наличие символа в значении переменной (PHP)

Tags: php

Мне нужно проверить, есть ли символ `@` в значении переменной. Пробовал `strpos` но он, как оказалось, вообще не для этого.

Comment: `if (preg_match("/@/", $str)) echo "Есть!";` Из предыдущего вопроса могу сделать вывод, что таким способом происходит валидация email. Для этого есть готовая PHP функция http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.examples.validation.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` как раз поможет.

```
$str = 'example@text';
$symbol = '@';
$isSymbolExist = strpos($str, $symbol) !== false;

echo $isSymbolExist ? "Присутствует" : "Отсутствует";
```

`strpos` [возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки в строке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php).
Позиция первого символа - 0. Поэтому для выяснения, если ли символ в строке, проверяем, что `strpos` возвращает значение, отличное от `false`, используя строгое сравнение.